# How to make Navigation work with Routes if they are in the different packages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some components in react App that I moved to a separate lerna package (apart from App.js and Routes.js) and it caused that my Navigation together with History stopped working). Any suggestion how to fix this separation that it work to Navigate to different URL?

Here are the files in that separate packages:

History.js:

```
 import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

 export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Navigation.js

```
 import history from '../utils/History';

  export default function Nav(loc, state) {
  history.push(loc, state);
  }
```

function in the class that I want t work with Nav
import Nav from '../Navigation';

```
     class MyComponent extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }

    handleClick(c) {  
    Nav('/main/' + c.name;)
    }
```

And here is Routes from another package(simplified)

```
  import { MyComponent } from '@MyComponents';
  import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

  const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
  <Route
  exact
  path='/'
  render={props => (
      <MyComponent
        {...props}      
      />bla...bla..))
```

I get my URL in the browser http://localhost:3000/main/componentname
But it doesn't redirect to the URL, only if I refresh

Any suggestions how I can make Navigation work if Routes is in one component and Navigation + History in another? Callback functions a bit difficult to implement if the Application becomes too complicated. Is there any other ways to fix it?

Comment: You can not just slash the code base randomly into different packages. A package is supposed to be independent. Each package is supposed to work on its own, or at the very least by importing another package, rather than just using some of the content of another package at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need `Navigation.js` & `History.js` you just change your `YourComponent` with:

`YourComponent`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(c) {
  
this.props.history.push(`/main/${c.name}`)
}
```

To understand how to implement this, you need to know that when a component is rendered by the router, three properties are passed as parameters:

1. match
2. location
3. history

in this case we use `history` in `this.props.history` to push our path into `/main/${c.name}`

Comment: hook can only be used inside the functional component what about class component?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot about that... let me search by the way...

Comment: please check my edited answers.. hopefully works.. ive tested it. and its works for me.

Comment: Great and it works! Thank you

Comment: can you make my answers is best answer :D